# Can this BubbleSort method be minimized any further?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to write a bubblesort method that needs to be able to sort on demand in both descending and ascending order while using a minimum amount of duplicate code.

So far this has been my temporal solution:

```
public void burbuja() {
    String TipoOrdenamiento = "Max";
    int i, j, aux;

    for (i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (j = A.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (TipoOrdenamiento == "Min") {
                if (A[j - 1] > A[j]) {
                    aux = A[j - 1];
                    A[j - 1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = aux;
                }
            }
            if (TipoOrdenamiento == "Max") {
                if (A[j - 1] < A[j]) {
                    aux = A[j - 1];
                    A[j - 1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you guys may notice, there's very little actual difference between ascending and descending sorting so I'm very curious to know if there are any neat tricks that allow me to compact my method further.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Side node: Strings should be compared with `equals` method.

Comment: I don't see the point of `TipoOrdenamiento` at all. You should probably provide two sort methods rather than this, but if you insist on one the second test of `TipoOrdenamiento` should be replaced by an `else`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean to denote if the comparison between j and j-1 should be true or false.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] A, String TipoOrdenamiento) {
    boolean increasingOrder = TipoOrdenamiento == "Min";
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = A.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            if (A[j - 1] < A[j] != increasingOrder && A[j - 1] != A[j]) {
                int aux = A[j - 1];
                A[j - 1] = A[j];
                A[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will cause it to swap equal items, which creates more work and also violates the normal bubblesort's guarantee of stability.

Comment: Fixed by adding  && A[j - 1] != A[j]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java, [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is nice way to achieve generality:

```
class MinComp implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return -1;
        if (a == b)
            return 0;
        if (a > b)
            return -1;
    }
}

public class Bubble
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MinComp minComp = new MinComp();
        burbuja(minComp);
    }

    static public void burbuja(Comparator comp) 
    {
        int i, j, aux;
        for (i = 1; i < A.length; i++) 
        {
            for (j = A.length - 1; j >= i; j--) 
            {
                if (comp.compare(A[j - 1], A[j]) > 0) 
                {
                    aux = A[j - 1];
                    A[j - 1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By defining different type of comparators, you can choose various orderings.

Comment: The `return b-a;` is a bad practice. If `b-a` results in integer overflow, then it will return an erroneous result. For example, if `b == int.MAX_VALUE` and `a` is negative (like -2), then the result will be negative, signifying that `b < a`. You really should use `return int.Compare(b, a);`

Comment: @Jim doesn't overflow lead to a thrown exception in general? Or this is a difference between .NET and JVM?

Comment: @PaulStelian: As far as I know, integer overflow and underflow do not cause exceptions in Java. In .NET, they *can* throw exceptions if you enable it in project options or if you are in a [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) context. In any case, an integer comparison shouldn't throw an exception or return an erroneous result.

Comment: Updated comparator not to use subtract operation.

Comment: And for this case it's sufficient to define *one* `Comparator`. To switch sort order, one can simply wrap the existing `Comparator` using `Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator)` (or `comparator.reversed()` in Java 8).

Comment: Just a couple of notes. There's no need for the `if (a > b)` in your `compare` function. If the code gets to that point, you already know that `a > b`. Also, you could replace the entire function body with `return a.compareTo(b);`